# Expected number of tries before all elements of sample space have occurred.

Tags: probability, statistics, coupon-collector

We have a bag with 4 balls, one white, one black, one blue and one red. We are drawing balls **with** replacement. Find the expected value of the number of tries needed to draw all four colours.

More general:
We have a uniform discrete distribution. What is the expected value of the number of tries needed until all elements of the sample space have occurred.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Comment: Consider a Markov process with states corresponding to the number of colors which have been sampled as of the present step.